# How can I pass a Paint or Color to my new object that is using the onDraw() method from an activity?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm trying to create some pixels with a random color by passing the color into the constructor as I'm creating the object. I can't seem to do it no matter what I try.

Here is my code..

**Object to be drawn**

```
public class Particle extends View{

    private int locationX;
    private int locationY;
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;
    private Paint color;
    private Rect rect;


    public Particle(Context context, int locationX, int locationY, int sizeX, int sizeY, Paint color) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
        this.color = color;


        rect = new Rect();
        color = new Paint();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        rect.set(0,0, sizeX, sizeY);
        color.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            //this is where it fails, the color defaults to black. 
            //will not take color = new Paint(Color.RED); from MainActivity
            //as parameter.

        color.set(color);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, color);
    }


}
```

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Particle particle;
    private Paint color;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        color = new Paint(Color.RED);
        particle = new Particle(this, 0, 0, 450, 120, color);
        setContentView(particle);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already overriding your `color`with `new Paint()` in the constructor. Then when you call `color.set(Color)` you are not changing it.

I suggest you pass the color as `int` in the constructor and then use `setColor`

```
public Particle(Context context, int locationX, int locationY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int paintColor) {

    (...)

    color = new Paint();
    color.setColor(paintColor);


}
```

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us. Glad I could help